# How to avoid error message "no main manifest attribute, in MyApp.jar"?

Tags: intellij-idea, deployment, jar, manifest.mf, vaadin-spring-boot

When I try to run a (Vaadin Spring Boot) application I created in Intellij Idea:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar
```

... I get the following error message:

"no main manifest attribute, in MyApp.jar"

I tried several of the solutions to this problem provided in posts pertaining to the same problem but I keep getting this error message.

Does anybody know a solid way to avoid this error message?

By the way:

the manifest file does exist:

[image]

and has the following content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.my_app.MyAppApplication
```

************************************UPDATE***********************************

MINIMAL EXAMPLE:

Using SpringInitializr (https://start.spring.io), I created a mini-app called minimalExample2.
The SpringInitializr tags used are:

[image]

After creating a jar-file, the project-structure looks as follows:

[image]

The content of the MANIFEST.MF file is the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.example.minimalExample2.MinimalExample2Application
```

When I want to run the app using

```
java -jar minimalExample2.jar
```

... I get the following error message:

"no main manifest attribute, in minimalExample2.jar"

You can easily replicate this app in a few seconds by selecting the two tags "Web" and "Vaadin" in Springinitializr and then clicking on "Generate Project".

Comment: Are there any jars with the digital signatures in the dependencies? Are there any jars with their own manifest files that can override IntelliJ IDEA manifest? You should share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ... I have now created a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: The problem is that other manifest files from the jars override the manifest created by IntelliJ IDEA. [See here for details](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116209#comment=27-656589). I'm also not sure you can package a complex Spring Boot application in a single jar file without special hacks. You may better use Maven fatjar plug-in or some other approach.